# How to send email in MySQLi or PDO?

Tags: php

I can't understand how to use email function in MySQLi PHP or with PDO.
so please help me.
My code:

```
$to = "xyz@gmail.com"; 
$from = $_REQUEST['email'];
$subject = "Client Contact Detail";
$subject2 = "Company  reply";
$message = 'Hello We are here';
$message2 = 'Our Details';
$headers = "From:" . $from;
$headers  .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers2 = "From:" . $to; 
$headers2  .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
$headers2 .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";   
 //echo "<pre>";
 //print_r($message)."<br/>";
 //print_r($message2);
 //exit;
@mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
@mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
      header('location:index.php');
```

Comment: Neither mysqli nor PDO has abaolutely nothing to do with sending mails. These two APIs are intended to interact with a database, not SMTP server.

Comment: Configure an SMTP server and use it for sending mails. There are two parts of it.
1. Configuring the SMTP server, if you don't have already one.
2. Using that server in your code to send mails.